# get webpage URL(moving to other page without changing URL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Website address is http://bbn.kiwoom.com/bbn.corpAnalCRList.do (is not my site)

I want to get the webpage `URL` **(pic 2)** that you can move by clicking red box or calling js `function(green box)` like **pic 1**.

[pic1&pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvuF.png)

But the page `URL` doesn't change. I want to provide the page link(a tag) for other people at my website.

How to get the page `URL` **(pic 2)**? or Is there other solution for the page link(a tag) like using `javascript function`?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want that the page URL change or do not change?

Comment: http://bbn.kiwoom.com/bbn.corpAnalCRList.do is not my site. I want to get the pic2 page URL and provide that URL(a tag) for other people on my site.

Comment: You should examine the body of the function "fnDetail". And post it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want, you can do easily with angular ng-include or object/iframe:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.templates =
      [ { name: 'pic1.html', url: 'https://www.google.com.br'},
        { name: 'pic2.html', url: 'http://www.google.com.br'} ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
   <option value="">(blank)</option>
  </select>
  url of the template: <code>{{template.url}}</code>
  <hr/>
  <div class="slide-animate-container">
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>
     <object type="text/html" data="{{template.url}}"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
    </object>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

(blank)
  
  url of the template: `{{template.url}}`

---

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use client routing - changing the url hash tag. Look at this small js library http://sammyjs.org/

You define your detail route, handling this route you will be showing your detail.